# Appropriate HTTP status for redirecting to authentication in a REST api

Tags: api, rest, http, authentication, jwt

I'm kind of surprised that, after searching for this for a while, I didn't find as many answers as I thought would be out there (well I found none), so maybe by asking it here we can help improve search results.

I'm building a REST api which has JWT-based authentication. There is an /auth/login route which returns the token after login/password verification, and the token is subsequently sent in every route in a Authorization http header.

Not, suppose that someone queries another route (say, /cars), without sending the token (that is, before logging in). If I return a 401 unauthorized, I can make the frontend query /auth/login to get the token.

But, strictly speaking, this does not conform to the REST specification, because every resource should be discoverable from the initial one, and a client accessing /cars and receiving a 401 will not know about /auth/login.

So another option would be a redirection like 302. But this semantics means that the resource was temporarily moved, and this is not the case (the resource is still /cars, you just need to authenticate first).

So, what is the correct way to do this procedure in a "true" rest api?

Answer (score 5):

I 100% agree, and that's why I proposed this standard:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pot-authentication-link-01

The idea is that for cases like this, you should be able to return a `Link` header with an `authentication` rel, so the client can discover how to proceed.